# how I can connect HTML to java to add values in database

Tags: java, database, jsp

I want to enter data in database entered from jsp file and dont know how to connect them. Can any one suggest me to connect both files and to add the data entered in jsp form ?

This is my jsp and java files...

**test1.java**

```
package P1;  

import java.sql.*;  


class test1 {  
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException  {  


            Connection con = null;  

            try {  
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
            }  
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {  
                System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");  
                System.exit(1);  
            }  

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.106.87:1521:ORA11G","fuel_db","foel");  
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();  

           String command = "INSERT INTO student (name, rollno, class, mobileno) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";  
           statement.executeUpdate(command);  

           con.close();  

       }  

}
```

**test1.html**

**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>FORM</title>

            <script type="text/javascript">


        <%
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String roll = document.getElementById("rollno");
        String clas = document.getElementById("class");
        String mobile = document.getElementById("mobileno");

        test1 myTest = new test1();
        myTest.submitData();
        %>



            function getvalues()
            {

                    var name = document.getElementById("name");
                    var roll = document.getElementById("rollno");
                    var clas = document.getElementById("class");
                    var mobile = document.getElementById("mobileno");
            }

            function num(e) 
            {
                    var k;
                    document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
                    return (!((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8));
            }

            </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test1.java" method="post" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>roll:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="rollno" maxlength="5" onkeypress="return num(event)"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>class:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="class" maxlength="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mobileno" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return num(event)"></td>
                </tr>       
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getvalues()"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**

Comment: This is not JSP. In JSP file Java statements are written in <% %> block. You are getting confused somewhere. JSP is Java in HTML!

Comment: must have pasted it twice by mistake

Comment: You will be needing `Servlets`.... [A Servlet and JSP Tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/)

Comment: ^ all,
Sorry typo error, i want to redirect html data to database in java file.

Comment: @blackbee Please don't put your suggestions or what you think in Answers section. Put it in comment section.People may downvote!

Comment: @AniketThakur suggest me how I can connect them. i mean using which methods ??

Comment: @Pratik First thing your question is not complete. You are not showing your `test1.jsp` file and enough information. Take a look at link given in previous comment.

Comment: @AniketThakur
Edited, der is my HTML code above. please gimme the solution......

Comment: @Pratik Javascript is client side and not server side so whatever you are doing is wrong. You must get all the values to server side using POST method when you submit your form and then store it in your DB,

Answer (score 4):

I won't go by your code. But the example here will be enough.
The standard way of passing/submitting data to the server in the pure `Servlets/JSP` world is by using `HTML` form, i.e. the same way as when use other server side languages for example php. And it doesn't matter whether it is a pure HTML page or JSP page. The recommended/most used method of submitting data from the form to the server is `POST` or `GET`.
Its standard way to submit data using POST method and respectively to process the submitted data using the `doPost()` method in your servlet.
for example:

```
<form name="something" method="post" action="<servlet-name>"> //if u want to change the action to something else then u need to modify your xml file.
<input type="text" name="username"/>
<input type="submit" name="submitit" value="submited"/>
</form>
```

now in the servlet under the doPost(...) write

```
if(request.getParameter("submitit").equals("submitted")){
String username=request.getParameter("username");
//now u can run a query and insert ito to database;
}
```

in the end you can redirect it another page with

```
`response.sendRedirect();`
```

or any other way
may i assume that you are using eclipse Java EE ide for development. then u need not worry about integrating them, eclipse would prepare the xml files for you once you create a new Java EE project. and if not then u have to do it manually, i once tried to do it, but I couldn't succeed.
here is a link: that would interset you, i hope: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

this is bad thing, but i will edit the code for you. by the way, i am removing the javascript. KISS (keeping it simple silly).. :)
ur jsp page would be:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>FORM</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test1" method="post" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>roll:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="rollno" maxlength="5"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>class:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="class" maxlength="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mobileno" maxlength="10"></td>
                </tr>       
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>

and the servlet will be:

import java.sql.*;  


class test1 {  
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException  {  


            Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            try {  
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
            }  
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {  
                System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");  
                System.exit(1);  
            }  

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.106.87:1521:ORA11G","fuel_db","foel");  

String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String roll = document.getElementById("rollno");// idk why roll no is string
        String clas_s = document.getElementById("class");
        String mobile = document.getElementById("mobileno");  
try {
           String query= "INSERT INTO student (name, rollno, class, mobileno) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";  
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1,name);
pstmt.setString(2,roll);
pstmt.setString(3,clas_s);
pstmt.setString(4,mobile);
           pstmt.executeUpdate();  

           con.close();  
    }
catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();}

response.sendRedirect("confirm.jsp");

       } 
}
```

donot ask me about the braces.. fix it yourself.

Comment: Should have been posted as comment

Comment: Sorry typo error, i want to redirect html data to database in java file

Comment: @Pratik i edited my answer a bit

Comment: @blackbee
Sorry sir but I really dont understand it. pls tell me the changes needed in jsp file. i.e. methods or else.

Comment: @Pratik If you want to achieve this then you have to learn Web App stuff by yourself. It will come handy in long run. [A Simple Servlet Example – (Write, Deploy, Run)](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/)

Comment: @Smit
what changes/addition are needed in jsp file ??

Comment: @Pratik This is my last comment. Its very late here and I am going to sleep. Anyway follow this link try to understand this code given in tutorial. This is simplest `servlet` tutorial I can find for you. Dont ask for changes or additions, they wont help you anyway. [Java Server-Side Programming](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaServlets.html). The time you are wasting here for help, better utilize it trying to understand it and implement it. Will help you in long run as everyday new technology emerges and you have to constantly learn them to keep your self in competition.

Answer (score 0):

First create some method like submitData(data) in your Java class.

```
public class test1 {  

        public void submitData(String name,String rollno,String classData,String mobileno) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException  {  


            Connection con = null;  

            try {  
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
            }  
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {  
                System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");  
                System.exit(1);  
            }  

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.106.87:1521:ORA11G","fuel_db","foel");  
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();  

           String command = "INSERT INTO student (name, rollno, class, mobileno) VALUES (" + name + "," + rollno + "," + classData + "," + mobileno + ");";  
           statement.executeUpdate(command);  

           con.close();  
       }  
}
```

In your HTMl page index.html or index.jsp, you need to put a form and then post it to JSP page which has the logic I have mentioned below.

```
<FORM NAME="form1" ACTION="ProcessData.jsp" METHOD="POST">
```

In your JSP page you may get data when a form is submitted using POST method. Get all those variables using request.getParameter("name")

Then in your JSP put that java code in <%  %> blocks inside body tag. **Remember JSP is Java in HTML!**
In your ProcessData.jsp

```
<%
String name = request.getParameter("name");
//add null checks and all
//Similarly get all datamobileno etc
//then call your submitData() method
test1 myTest = new test1();
myTest.submitData(....)
%>
```

Also take care of naming conventions.

In java

1. Classes name start with Caps. So class name must be Test1 and not test1.
2. Functions, variables must be in **Camel case** like myTest.

Comment: Your answer sounds like Web Application. If thats the case then you should be mentioning some server will be required to perform this. Correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: Sir, What more is needed ??
@Smit

Comment: @Smit Obviously his HTML page from where he extracts data must be hosted on some server. No point of JSP without a server.

Comment: @Pratik as I mentioned in comments on your question Javascript is client side and not server side so whatever you are doing is wrong. You must get all the values to server side using POST method when you submit your form and then store it in your DB,

Comment: @AniketThakur By looking at OPs code it looks like that he is practicing. @ Pratik Take a look at `servlets` tutorial. Read it properly. Even if you want to run `servlets` on local machine. You will be needing some server like `Tomcat` or `Glassfish` etc. I am telling you this because whatever you are asking is to big to cover. Read tutorial try and then post a question with your specific problems.

Comment: @Smit I don't think there is any need of servlets here. You can simply configure Tomcat to display index.JSP and specify some processData.JSP on form submit(POST) and redirect back to index.JSP on successful submission of data. Java script to validate before posting. Still knowing servlets will clear all concepts like doGet, doPost methods.

Comment: @AniketThakur
Sir, I have edited the code, and also changed to POST, now what do I have to do ???
I am not that kind of beginner, I hv some knowledge of this.
I am already working on Tomcat.

Comment: @AniketThakur I must say that I dont code much now a days and may be I am missing something. But according to my knowledge `Servlets` are needed to do this kind of operations. I am not sure the way you are talking about how this can be done.